# Consume messages from the last 5 minutes and dump it into another topic, cyclically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to consume messages in a 5-minute time window and count the number of messages that arrived. After that, I want to copy the last message that arrived in the group, copy it, edit its field "count" to match the number of messages in the timeslice, and send it to a topic.

Hoever, I'm having trouvle with the windowing part, need help on that.
I've made my own JSON Serdes (MessageSerde), and the Class Message represents the JSON message, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do now regarding the windowing process.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    final KStream<String, Message> inputStream = 
    builder

    .stream("users", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde));

    inputStream
    .filter(new Predicate<String, Message>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s, Message s2) {
        return s2.getPriority().equals("Low");
        }
    })


    KTable<Windowed<String>, Message> fiveMinuteWindowed = inputStream

    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)))
    .count()
    .to("test-filter", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde));


    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
```

## Update

After the suggestion from Matthias, I've created this code but am running into a few compilation errors, the in the .to method:

```
   inputStream

     .filter(new Predicate<String, Message>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s, Message s2) {
        return s2.getPriority().equals("Low");
      }
    })
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)))
    .aggregate(
    new Initializer<Message>() { /* initializer */
        @Override
        public Message apply() {
            Message tuple = new Message();
            return tuple;
        }
    },
    new Aggregator<String, Message, Message>() { /* adder */
        @Override
        public Message apply(String aggKey, Message curMsg, Message tuple) {

            tuple.setCount(tuple.getCount() + 1);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

            try{
                Date parsedDate_cur = dateFormat.parse(curMsg.getTimestamp());
                Timestamp timestamp_cur = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate_cur.getTime());
                Date parsedDate_agg = dateFormat.parse(tuple.getTimestamp());
                Timestamp timestamp_agg = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate_agg.getTime());

                if(timestamp_cur.after(timestamp_agg)){
                    tuple.setTimestamp(timestamp_cur.toString());
                }

                tuple.setId(curMsg.getId());
                tuple.setSourceip(curMsg.getSourceip());
                tuple.setType(curMsg.getType());
                tuple.setPriority(curMsg.getPriority());
                tuple.setName(curMsg.getName());
                tuple.setMetadata(curMsg.getMetadata());  
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error parsing dates"); 
            }    
            return tuple;
        }
    },
    Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde))
    .suppress(untilWindowCloses(unbounded())) 
    .toStream();
    .to("test-filter", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), MessageSerde));
```

The errors include:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/x/Documents/project/src/main/java/com/streams/app/App.java:[194,9] no suitable method found for to(java.lang.String,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced<java.lang.String,Pojo.Message>)
[ERROR]method org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.to(java.lang.String,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.String>,Pojo.Message>) is not applicable
[ERROR](argument mismatch; inference variable K has incompatible equality constraints org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String)
[ERROR]method org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.to(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopicNameExtractor<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.String>,Pojo.Message>,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.String>,Pojo.Message>) is not applicable
[ERROR](argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopicNameExtractor<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.String>,Pojo.Message>)
```

Comment: first of all, when you invoke `inputStream.filter(..)`, a new KStream instance created, so you need: `inputStream = inputStream.filter(..)`. second, when you do `windowedBy`, your key becomes `Windowed` and not a `String`. after `. count()`, your value becomes `Long`. and why do you use `windowedBy(TimeWindows` and `Materialized with SessionStore`?

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi The Materialized was used purely based on examples I saw online because I have no idea what to put in the count()

Comment: edited the question for a better understanding

Comment: I guess, you might want to use `aggregate()` instead of `count()` to control the output format (`count()` limits you to `Long` and value type). Second, `suppress()` might be your friend to get only one record per time window in the output topic.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you! I'll try what you suggested. I'm really desperate about getting this to work so any help is welcome at this point

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I've edited the post with changes I've done with the information you gave me, if you could give it a look, please

Comment: The result of the aggregation has type `<Windowed<K>,V`, and thus your need to provide a `TimeWindowedSerde` in `to()`.

Comment: Are there online examples of this Serde I can use? @MatthiasJ.Sax